# SwiftUI - Issue with ContextMenu on a page containing a List view overriding the ContextMenu of another page (watchOS)

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I have reduced my problem to the following views which are [embedded in two WKHostingControllers  paging between each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC1Zi.png).

```
struct FirstContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FirstContentView")
            .contextMenu {
                Text("FirstContextMenu")
            }
    }
}

struct SecondContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("SecondContentView")
        }.contextMenu {
            Text("SecondContextMenu")
        }
    }
}
```

[When I run it this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrqr1.jpg). As soon as page 2 is loaded the context menu of page 1 remains replaced by the one of page 2. This issue only happens if a List view is anywhere in the body of SecondContentView, even if the `.contextMenu` is not attached to it or the List is encapsulated into another View. Replacing List for example with Group works, but I need the list behaviour for my items.

Has anybody also run into this issue? How can I fix it so the context menu works as intended (?) on both pages?

Comment: Is there any specific reason not use pure SwiftUI navigation? Why do use Storyboard with injected SwiftUI if all that is possible by only SwiftUI?

Comment: I guess I can find a way to only use SwiftUI to solve this issue. I have not thought about trying to remove the pagination between the WKHostingControllers since at first glance it seemed to be the way to go on watchOS. After looking closer, I found a [PageView](https://github.com/fredyshox/PageView) implementation which tries to combat the use of multiple WKHostingControllers. I did some testing and it seems to be working. I only have to do some modifications so that only the context menu of the current page is active. Thank you for the idea of using only SwiftUI :)